# Why can't I write PDO prepared statements in quotes?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I had the following piece of code with [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `myColumn1` FROM my_table '.
                       'WHERE `myColumn2`=:val LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bindValue(":val", $value);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This works fine. It sends the following query:

```
113 Query   SELECT `myColumn1` FROM my_table WHERE `myColumn2`=":val" LIMIT 1
```

and it returns the correct value.

But it doesn't work if I change the first line to

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `myColumn1` FROM my_table '.
                       'WHERE `myColumn2`=":val" LIMIT 1');
```

or

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `myColumn1` FROM my_table '.
                       'WHERE `myColumn2`=':val' LIMIT 1');
```

The same query is sent, but PDO returns false.

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: May I ask a question? What for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the page you quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

> The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this.

The purpose of the quotation marks is to delimit string data from the rest of the query, since it cannot easily be separated (unlike numbers, which have an obvious format). Since using prepared statements means that query and data are passed separately, the quotes are unnecessary.

Comment: AFAIK this is not true - prepared statements are parsed by the server including the placeholder and the parameters passed separately via an API. Since quotes are only relevant to statement parsing, there is no need for them at all.

Comment: thanks for this answer. I've read the german version of the page and the translation of quote is ... well ... different to the translation I would have used.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt This is indeed true in databases that support prepared statements, but PDO emulates the behaviour for other databases. I'll try to clear up the language.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Fancy elaborating?

Comment: I wouldn't call it elaboration. I'd rather call it replacing false statements with true ones.

Comment: If you want to say what's wrong, kindly do so. If you want to say what's right, even better. If you want to use this site to provide useful information, fantastic. Otherwise...

Comment: First one was about your answer before edit, I deleted id. second one is about `dates, which have an obvious format` and thus require no quoting. Are you sure?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel This is a fun game. We should play it more often.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of prepared statements are that types are handled for you (sort of...).  In other words, prepared statements allow MySQL (or whatever RDBMS) to decide how to handle data.  When putting quotes, that would force it to be a string which doesn't make sense.  If it's supposed to be a string, then the server will handle that.